# JDBC Driver for SQL Server throws SqlServerException: 'Operation not supported' while calling a stored procedure which uses cursors

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, wso2

I am trying to call a stored procedure using *JDBC driver 6.0* for SQL Server and getting the error `Operation not supported` if the stored procedure uses cursors, XML manipulation and/or temporary tables.

If I modify the stored procedure definition to have a simple select query then it works but if it has cursors or temporary tables it throws the error `Operation not supported`.

I am using *SQL Server 2008*.

I call the stored procedure from *WSO2 DSS server*

The exact error which I get is this :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
>                  at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
>                  at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)

Here is the complete Stack-trace for the issue:

```
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': This operation is not supported.

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RMLDS
Location: C:\WSO2SO~1\WSO2DS~1.1\bin\..\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1479805129410stap-capp_1.0.0.car\RMLDS_1.0.0\RMLDS-1.0.0.dbs
Description: 
Default Namespace: 
Current Request Name: _putorionsetuppagecount
Current Params: {xml=23}
Nested Exception:-
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
           at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
           at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:354)
           at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
           at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
           at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
           at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
My stored procedure was taking a string as input, but the content of that string was xml. So wso2 dss TryIt tool was failing with above error because i was passing it as `<test/>`, but i needed to pass it as `&lt;Test/&gt;`.

I hope this helps others

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be the reason , A server-side database cursor is not created if the requested result set type is a forward-only result set. May be try to set SelectMethod property as cursor.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/mssqlserver.html

Comment: No it didn't work. i wrote a simple java app for doing the same thing and it worked there !! . seems that some problem with wso2 dss server. or may be i am missing something..